# Magento 2 - What is the logic behind the isSalable() function?

Tags: magento, magento2

Can somebody explain the logic of the `isSalable()` function?

I have started to understand the logic but I know there is something more.

> If "Backorders" false then "Qty" should be grater than the "Minimum
>   Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" ....

Do anyone have the complete logic?
Thank you

Comment: I think you should view some document: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038988/what-is-the-difference-between-issaleable-and-isavailable https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5238/where-does-is-salable-come-from

Answer (score 0):

This function is in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` Model

Generally it checks product status and based on that gives output.